# Theme image broken link

Tags: 7, media

I am recreating an existing website and part of the process is enabling a theme from the same existing site on my new version.

The theme is called **microsite** and has an image located in **/microsite/images/**.

In the original site, the image from the above directory is loaded and displayed in a block.
I copied the code from the block of the original site, pasted and saved in a block of my new site. The HTML markup is the following.

```html
<a href="/publications" target="_self">
  <img src="/sites/all/themes/microsite/images/image.jpg" />
</a>
```

Using the exact HTML markup in my recreated site with the same theme and path to image shows a broken image link. The link shows up as    http://192.10.10.1/sites/all/themes/microsite/images/image.jpg instead of
http://192.10.10.1/mysite/sites/all/themes/microsite/images/image.jpg.

To resolve this, I set `$base_url` in settings.php to http://192.10.10.1/mysite, but the link is still broken.

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`url()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/7) function to perform the path/URL magic for you. Note that you will have to change the block's input format to "PHP code" for this to work.

```
<a href="<?php print url('publications'); ?>" target="_self">
  <img src="<?php print url('sites/all/themes/microsite/images/image.jpg'); ?>" />
</a>
```

(All of the above could be accomplished by a call to `theme_image()` followed by `l()` but that would obscure the answer. Also, it's good practice to use `path_to_theme()` to get the path to the current theme.)

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the first slash from `src` in your theme to

```
<img src="sites/all/themes/microsite/images/image.jpg" />
```

That first slash is indicating that it is relative to your web root rather than your Drupal root.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

If none of these answers work, make sure you have set the RewriteBase in your `.htaccess` file to be in the virtual directory /mysite

```
# Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
# VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
# For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
# modify the following line:
 RewriteBase /mysite
#
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<img src="<?php print drupal_get_path("microsite", "theme"); ?>/images/image.jpg" />
```